# Why Typescript prioritizing type inferring over generic type with default?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

Do you have an explanation why TS doesn't infer the `string` type in the first example?
Despite I used string as a default for the generic `T` in the `bar` function?
Thanks

The error (in example 1):

> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | undefined'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.ts(2345)

```
// Example 1 (has error)

const baz = (a: unknown) => a;

const bar = <T extends string | number = string>(): T => {
  return baz('some_value') as T;
};

const foo = (str?: string) => `${str} is string`;

// Error!!

foo(bar());
```

I've two options for a solution but I'm not sure why they work:

- extracting the `bar()` call into constant (example 2)
- removing the options operator from `str` (example 3)

```
// Example 2 (no error)

const baz = (a: unknown) => a;

const bar = <T extends string | number = string>(): T => {
  return baz('some_value') as T;
};

const foo = (str?: string) => `${str} is string`;

const barResult = bar();
foo(barResult);
```

Remove the `?`:

```
// Example 3 (no error)

const baz = (a: unknown) => a;

const bar = <T extends string | number = string>(): T => {
  return baz('some_value') as T;
};

const foo = (str: string) => `${str} is string`;

foo(bar());
```

Comment: I **think** it's because TypeScript isn't using the default, but can't use any of the candidate inferences either, because the only candidate inference is `string | undefined` (from `foo`'s `arg?: string`), but that can't be used for `bar`'s `T`, so you end up not using the default and not using an inferred parameter.

Comment: But just for completeness or whatever: The implementation of `bar` is incorrect, for two reasons: 1. `getItem` never returns `number`; and 2. `getItem` sometimes returns `null` (if there is nothing in storage for the given key). So for instance, `x = bar<number>()` would result in TypeScript thinking `x` was a number when it fact it's a string or `null`. The only proper type for `bar`'s return value, for `bar` as written, is `string | null`.

Comment: Interesting @T.J.Crowder , Thank you. So you say that the default is just a candidate for inferring. And the function call inference is actually stronger?

Comment: I used `getItem` as an example (bad one) for a third-party function, I'll try to think on a better one.

Comment: *"So you say that the default is just a candidate for inferring."* No, the default is what's used if there is no type argument provided at all. But in this case, there's a *possible* type argument, which is the one that's inferred from `foo`'s `arg`. It's just that since it can't be used, it looks like the default isn't used either. But **I could easily be wrong**, I'm still fairly early on my TypeScript journey. :-) (I probably shouldn't have commented at all.)

Comment: I have to say that your explanation sounds correct, thanks for that.